# How to get the whole row of a table that has the maximum value of the key in adf?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have to get the data from a table by getting the maximum key of each value in adf dataflow, for example: Key: 1,2,3,4 ID:abc,abc,efg,efg
I have to get the data of each ID with the maximum value of the key in this case the Key 2 and 4.
I have tried to do it with an aggregate

Answer (score 0):

**In order to achieve your requirement follow below steps:**

1. In ADF create pipeline and ad take dataflow activity and add new dataflow.
2. In source of dataflow add your source file/table.
   [image]
   **Data preview:**
   [image]
3. After this take a window transformation and configure it as below:
   -- Over ID:
   [image]
   -- Sort  by Key:
   [image]
   -- keep Range by as it is and change window column as **column name** as `rownum` and **Expresssion** as `rowNumber()`:
   [image]
   **Data preview:**
   [image]
4. Take another window transformation and configure it as below:
   -- Over ID:
   [image]
   -- Keep Sort by and Range by as it is and change window column as **column name** as `last` and **Expresssion** as `last(rownum)`:
   [image]
   **Data preview:**
   [image]
5. Then take filter transformation and filter the rows where `rownum==last`:
   [image]
   **Data preview:**
   [image]
6. Then take a select transformation and delete the column we crated rownum and last.
   [image]

**OUTPUT:**
[image]